# only input check boxes that are checked in the first td in a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the the number of matches/length of: only input check boxes that are checked in the  first td in a tr?

this works:

```
$('#myTable').find('tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked').parents('tr').length;
```

this wont work

```
$('#myTable').find('tr td:eq(0) input[type=checkbox]:checked').parents('tr').length;
```

Comment: Why you use `.parents('tr')` ?

Comment: When you say `a tr`, do you mean a single `tr` or all the `tr's` in the table?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#myTable').find('tr td:first input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTable tr').find('td:eq(0) input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```